# tiny dtmf dialler

Tags: sensor, usb

I would like to create a small dtmf dialler that connects to a telephone line and dials a single preprogrammed telephone number when a set of contacts closes, how easy is this and how small could this device be?

Comment: I'd go for an el-Cheapo MP3 player with a single track. You can't get much cheaper and smaller than that by building it yourself

Comment: This question can't be answered without knowing how much design experience you have, and what development facilities are available.

Comment: How about using a simple electronic greeting card with a recordable message? Like these ones: http://goo.gl/fOYjL , http://goo.gl/9rDYf , http://goo.gl/gDrLE , http://goo.gl/J3iN2 . You would only need to record the DTMF tones on it.

Comment: While the design of such a system could be on topic here, discussion of how cheap or easy it is to make are not.  That is a retorical question likely to solicit opinion and debate without a real answer possible.

Answer (score 5):

Trivial to do with a single MCU if you can program MCUs.
For instance the MSP430 has a DTMF generation application note and sample code that shows you how to generate DTMF with them.  I don't recall what series chip they use, but I'm pretty sure it'd be one of the original low end series that is less than $3 in single quantity at DigiKey.
q.v.:
http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaae16/slaae16.pdf

So the thing is there are a bunch of DTMF generator ICs, I used to use ones like the TCP5088, TCP5089.  There were some from National, Mitel, Teltone, many more, but a lot of those chips have gone obsolete.  A quick non exhaustive search of Digikey and Mouser shows me that few if any of the classic old DTMF dialer ICs are still made, and no likely devices in the category of DTMF Dialer IC are even stocked by those major distributors.  Looks like Silicon Labs, Ixys, maybe ST might have something, I don't know, but the supply picture didn't look good and it's not clear they'd even do what you need.  If the SLICs with DTMF that SiLabs has are DTMF *encoders* and the SLIC function is CPE side and not CO line card side, you may have a solution with those.

There used to be ICs with DTMF tone generation capability, a keypad interface to scan a 4x4 keypad and dial the numbers, and, better yet, they had memory dial capabilities so you could preprogram a given multi digit number in to a memory location and dial it with a button press.  That would accomplish your application right there if you could find such a chip still.  NTE has some DTMF ICs, but I have no idea on the specifics.

Problem is the ICs like that are dumb and often don't have features that you might need.  You might need a delay after the contact closure happens before dialling.  You might need more debounce for the switch contact.  You might want to have the chip check for dial tone before dialling.  You might want to check for call progress to indicate if the call went through or got a busy signal or SIT or whatever, redial if needed.  Then after it dials, then what, you wait for an answer?  Decode DTMF looking for a "I got it" signal?  Wait 30 seconds then hang up?  Stay connected as long as your trigger contact is closed?  The dumb DTMF ICs don't generally do all of those things, so using a MCU would be useful if you want a reliable solution.

Also if you were going to switchhook the line and also trigger a "speed dial" button you'd need at least a 3PST contact relay, and by the time you add extra cost for the dedicated DTMF IC, more complex switching, et. al. you could have had a more reliable and maybe cheaper solution with a MCU.

The other thing you need is a SLIC aka DAA or line interface unit (LIU).  Basically that is a 2PST equivalent telecom line relay to switch the line, or an equivalent solid state line switch device to control off hook / on hook.  You need to have some transient protection in case of ESD, lightning surges, ringing voltages, etc. which can damage electronics on the phone line.  You need an impedance matching isolation transformer appropriate to telecom usage with an impedance appropriate for your telecom network (USA often 600 ohms), and a frequency responce sufficiently flat that it passes DTMF and call progress tones appropriately.  You used to be able to buy DAA / LIU units from TDK and other places, but now that POTS is almost obsolete, you may have to look around.  The relay (if not solid state), transformer (if not also solid state) and protection devices will be the bulk of the size of your unit other than the unspecified DC operational power supply for the dialer.  The dialing IC or microcontroller is usually a 20 pin 300 mil DIP or smaller.

So, really, figure out what you need, what work you're willing to do to get it, and proceed looking for a COTS board level product, a speed dialer IC, a finished LIU/DAA module, or some homebrew MCU / other solution.  You might be able to get a junk phone with speed dial and just hook a 4PST relay or other contact (you didn't say what the contact was) into its switchhook and speed dial button and call it done for a one off.

I'm probably not going out on too much of a limb to suspect someone probably has an arduino sketch to do this given a LIU and relay....

OBTW I think I've seen COTS board level products that do this in response to an alarm contact, they get used for remote facility monitoring, flood or intruder detection, maintenance indication, etc.  Search for autodialer or similar on google / aliexpress / dx etc. and you may find something.  Tiny?  Who knows.  Smallest I'd usually see for a LIU and DTMF dialer was about matchbox sized though it could be about half that easily enough. Sugarcube maybe.

There are still regulations in some parts of the world about equipment authorization and regulatory approvals to connect devices to the PSTN over POTS lines and such which you might care about if you're going to sell this thing or think you're at risk of getting shocked or damaging the network by a bad homebrew device.  The pre-approved LIU can take care of some of that.  Some of the other stuff doesn't matter so much for a dial only application without TX/RX otherwise.

Comment: +1... And yes, there are a few DTMF dialing POTS interfaced Arduino projects out there.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly easy. You can buy DTMF chips that you can attach a keyboard to and input a number and use "last number redial". I've actually designed one for a track-side telephone that just had one button and called a guy in his signal-box to open the barrier on a track-crossing point.

A couple of issues - you have to draw about 20mA (minimum) from the line to guarantee proper connectivity through to the PBX. You also need to pay-heed to having decent 600ohm return loss although for an autodialler that isn't as important as an actual telephone.

There'll be a few other issues like making sure your circuit is not polarity concious - a bridge rectifier will do that. You also have to, when activating the contact, have a small circuit that uses a FET or BJT for taking the line feed current (equivalent to lifting the hookswitch or handset). This needs a small delay of about 1 second before the dialler is activated.

You'll also need a small battery to keep the DTMF dialler powered during line outages - you don't want to lose the number you've stored etc..

Size - quite small - cigarette pack size is an overkill - matchbox size is pushing it slightly but dependent on the size of the battery. I'll try and find a basic circuit for you. Give me a while....

If all this sounds too daunting then maybe this project is not for you.

Additions/Edit - DTMF dialler available in UK at below GBP£1: -

[image]

Here's also a link to a handy page for making your own auto-dialler - I checked the circuit and it looks ok and uses the chip above.
http://www.nabilkarami.com/projects.php?show=project&id=16

Comment: I wonder if it might be easier to use a uC for this... I mean they have fairly robust square wave generation facilities.

Comment: +1, nice answer. A few suggested DTMF ICs might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to interface to an old phone to emulate the  off-hook & key presses.  Glue in appropriate electronic switches with a 4017 counter and clock and you have an auto dialer.

Comment: Are you suggesting a pulse dialer?

Comment: Many phone companies in the U.S. no longer support pulse dialing.